# Looping through november, december and subsequently january using VBA

Tags: loops, excel, vba

I'm intending to create a macro which finds a file corresponding to the current year and loop through its sheets. The sheets' names are corresponding to the month names (in Swedish). My problem is however that I due to possible deletion of data etc. in the files I import, I do not want to import data which is entered longer than 2 months ago, and loop from that corresponding month to today's month (well, actually to UBound(MyHeadings) as some data I want to extract is constant over the year).

```
Dim MonthNo As Integer 'Makes MonthNo = Month(Date) return an integer, instead of actual month name
MonthNo = Month(Date)
myHeadings = Split("Januari,Februari,Mars,April,Maj,Juni,Juli,Augusti,September,Oktober,November,December", ",") 
p3file = "C:\pathtofile\" 'Because Dir does not return pathfile. 
YearNo = Year(Date)
path3 = IIF(MonthNo-2, Dir("C:\pathtofile\" & "-" & YearNo-1 & ".xlsx"),Dir("C:\pathtofile\" & "-" & YearNo & ".xlsx"))

Do While Len(path3) > 0
    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(p3file & path3)
    For i = MonthNo To UBound(myHeadings)
        Set openWs = openWb.Sheets(CStr(YearNo))
        'Do things
        End If
    Next i
YearNo = YearNo + 1
path3 = Dir("C:\pathtofile\" & YearNo & ".xlsx")   
Loop
```

The above is what I've tried. The problem arises if MonthNo -2 is less than 0, since then I have to import the previous year's file (which I do by the IIf statement). The loop however becomes wrong. If the current month is, for instance, january 2015, I want to open up 2014's file, loop through november and december, then open up 2015 file and loop through january. Is there any neat way of achieving this?

Comment: Your condition `MonthNo-2` in IIF statement doesn't look right. It's false only for `MonthNo=2`, I guess it should be `MonthNo-2<=0`. Also I don't understand why the loop starts at `MonthNo` and not at `MonthNo-2`. `CStr(YearNo)` in the first line of looks suspicious too - probably it should be `myHeadings(i)`.

Comment: Make it so if MonthNo = 0 then its December of the year before and if MonthNo = -1 then it's November

Comment: @user3964075 Yes that is true! I edited my code in my program while I wrote it here, so I defined MonthNo differently. MonthNo = Month(Date)-2, which motivates why it is from MonthNo

Good Point with myHeadings(i) <=. Will edit tomorrow, will have to go ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could look like this:

```
Dim MonthNo As Integer, YearNo As Integer
Dim CurrentYear As Integer
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim i As Integer

Const MonthOffset As Integer = -2

CurrentYear = Year(Date)

StartDate = DateAdd("m", MonthOffset, Date)
MonthNo = Month(StartDate)
YearNo = Year(StartDate)

Do While YearNo <= CurrentYear
'Open file here
  For i = MonthNo To 12

    'Process sheets here

  Next i
  MonthNo = 1
  YearNo = YearNo + 1
Loop
```

This code should work OK for any month offset defined in the constant.

Comment: This helped me to get rid of the problem, and due to the clearness of the answer it helped me solve my issue with the two remaining loops which were of a different kind. Thanks specifically for the "DateAdd" function. Thought I had to do a bunch of if statements.